# Issue with daemons gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-daemons

I'm using daemons gem with Rails in addition to daemon_generator plugin. I'm getting this output in the daemons log file:

```
 Logfile created on Sat May 09 20:10:35 -0700 2009 by /
-below you find the most recent exception thrown, this will be likely (but not certainly) the exception that made the application exit abnormally ***
#<NameError: uninitialized constant SmsMessage>
-below you find all exception objects found in memory, some of them may have been thrown in your application, others may just be in memory because they are standard exceptions ***
#<NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory>
#<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>
#<fatal: exception reentered>
#<MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- ./config/global_constants.conf>
#<NameError: uninitialized constant SmsMessage>
```

I'm finding very hard to make sense from this output. It's displaying different error messages and I can tell it's not it's not the ./config/global_constants.conf issues because I don't call it inside the daemon file. Plus I don't think it's a memory issues as my Mac has 2GB of memory and not many programs running. as for the SmsMessage I'm calling it normally using:

```
scheduledMessagesParent = SmsMessage.valid.find(:all, :conditions => {:status => $SCHEDULED_MESSAGE})
```

which works elsewhere in my website!!
I noticed that the logger is called using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.info "....
```

Is it possible I have to specify my model's path in another way? I normally call the logger using logger.info without the need for ActiveRecord::Base. If so how to do that?

Any ideas how to go about debugging this problem? is there a way to display stack trace or better error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by loading the Rails environment with the Daemon. It wasn't included in the tutorial that I got the info from but it works now :)